# Garbled Triangles from VBO/Shader/MVP Matrix using OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vbo

Drawing with a regular VBO on older GLSL versions is not a problem but for whatever reason I get this result when using GLSL 3.3.

It should be drawing a 2x2 plane on each axis.

(Lighter colors are closer to the far plane, darker are closer to the near plane)
[image: Picture of problem]

One of the major changes with 3.3 was that you have to provide uniforms with your Model View Projection matrixes as opposed to using the old provided ones.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm almost certain it's something to do with the Model View Projection data. Here is the relevant code.

**Main draw method**

```
float r = 0.0f;
void display() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);         // And the depth buffer

    r += 0.001f;

    glUseProgram(program);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    GLuint uniformModel = glGetUniformLocation(program, "model");
    GLuint uniformView = glGetUniformLocation(program, "view");
    GLuint uniformProjection = glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection");

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(70.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 16.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformProjection, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glm::vec3 eye = glm::vec3(sin(r*0.33)*5.0f,5,cos(r*0.33)*5.0f);
    glm::vec3 center = glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(eye, center, up);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

    glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,  
            3,    
            GL_FLOAT, 
            GL_FALSE, 
            0, 
            (void*)0 
    );

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 18, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glFlush();  // Render now
}
```

**Vertex/Indices Array & Shader**

```
string vert
        = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;\n" 
        "uniform mat4 model;\n"
        "uniform mat4 view;\n"
        "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
        "void main(){\n" 
        " gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex,1.0f);\n" 
        "}";
string frag
        = "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec3 color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        " float lin = 1.0 / gl_FragCoord.w;\n"
        " float depth = (lin - 0.1) / (16.0 - 0.1);\n"
        " color = vec3(depth,depth,1.0f);\n"
        "}";

float* data = new float[36] {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
    1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
    -1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    0.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
    0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
    0.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,
    -1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,
    -1.0f,0.0f,1.0f
};

GLuint* indices = new GLuint[18] {
    0,1,2,
    0,3,2,
    4,5,6,
    4,7,6,
    8,9,10,
    8,11,10
};
```

**Init**

```
const int winSize = 1024;
void glInit(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitContextVersion(3,3);
    //glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE | GLUT_DEBUG);
    glutInitWindowSize(winSize, winSize);
    glutInitWindowPosition(25, 25);
    glutCreateWindow("Loading...");
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    glViewport (0, 0, winSize, winSize);
    camera.setPosition(0.0f,0.0f,4.0f);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vba);
    glBindVertexArray(vba);

    program = compileShader(vert, frag);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3*4*3*4, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);    


    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    while(!bExit) {
        string pre;
        pre.assign("Test Program - ");
        pre.append(std::to_string(fps));
        glutSetWindowTitle(pre.c_str());
        frames++;
        display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but setting the near plane to 0.0 in your projection matrix is normally a bad idea. Far/near should not be too large to give you reasonable depth precision. And having near at 0.0 makes far/near infinity.

Comment: Changed it to 0.1 but the mess still persists. At the very least that was some useful advice for future projects :P Thanks.

Comment: The indices look suspect to me. e.g., `{0, 1, 2}` has a different winding order to `{0, 3, 2}`. If the first is CCW, then the latter is CW.

Comment: I tried this same setup using glDrawArrays and got a similar garbled up mess of triangles. It really seems like it's something to do with the MVP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm an idiot and it was just a typo kind of error.

I define GLuint vbo in the init method AND on the scope of the program as well but the actual value of the vbo is only put into local variable. display() didn't have visibility of the vbo at all.

```
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
```

It's always the little things that cause ridiculous bugs. <_>